# Enabling the internet access for Blackberry SDK 9900 Simulator

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

I am new to developing for BB and I have an application which needs to connect to the internet. However, I am not really sure how to enable this. I googled it  and there seems to be various suggestions/solutions for this but none of them seem to work. Can anyone give other suggestions or directions ?

Comment: Did you configure wi-fi with the default network in your simulator?

Comment: refer my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541805/httpconnection-not-working-in-real-device-blackberry/12541836#12541836